# Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: networking, mysql, oracle, mysql-workbench

[image: Error Screenshortstrong text]

Currently, I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and  I've tried so much but still not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127839/oracle-sql-developer-failure-test-failed-the-network-adapter-could-not-estab), you may try the following:

> - Make sure your tnsnames.ora is complete and has the databases you wish to connect to
> - Make sure you can tnsping the server you wish to connect to
> - On the server, make sure it will be open on the port you desire with the specific application you are using.